# Custom UIView linked to UIViewController - how to handle button actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am confused with splitting components between UIViewController and UIView. Let's say I made custom UIView with subviews:

```
@interface CustomView : UIView

@property(strong, nonatomic) UITextField *textField;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *image;

@end
```

What I would like to achieve in controller is after pushing button from view I'm taking value from textField and push new navigationController. But I don't know how to do this properly. What I'm trying right now is something like:

```
@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
    [customView.searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPushSearchButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.view = customView;
}

- (void)didPushSearchButton {
    //pushing new viewController, but how can i get value from text field here?
}

@end
```

Can i say somehow for CustomViewController that it's view is of type CustomView? I would be able to get textField's value then, because I could type self.view.textField. Now after typing self.view - ViewController doesn't know anything about textField...

Comment: Are you using Xib for this custom view?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using a storyboard or a .xib file, then try this:

```
// CustomViewController.h
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) CustomView *view;

@end

// CustomViewController.m
@implementation CustomViewController

@dynamic view;

- (void)loadView {
    CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.applicationFrame];
    [customView.searchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPushSearchButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.view = customView;
}

@end
```

(Modified from "[Overriding uiviewcontroller's view property, done right](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/12/overriding-uiviewcontroller-s-view-property-done-right/)")

Comment: It works but is it good approach? If i have problem like this, doesn't it mean that I made architecture in a wrong way?

Comment: It is bad architecture. You should just add your custom view as a subview and set the view controller as the delegate to the custom view so it can call the view controller's methods or set it as the target for the button.